# Is "There's more sanctity in a dog's loyalty than there is in all your human laws." a quote from the Holy Bible?

Tags: bible, reference-request, scriptures

I just saw an episode of *The Simpson's* on television [(S28E22 - *Dogtown*)](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Dogtown_(The_Simpsons)), in which during a courtroom scene, the judge turns to the jury and says:

> *Now, I have a brief instruction for the jury:*
>
> ***"There's more sanctity in a dog's loyalty than there is in all your human laws."***

Then raises the court's Holy Bible and motions to it, as if quoting scripture.

Quite a profound and eloquent statement, but not one I've ever seen/heard in relation to any spiritual or religious texts. A cursory online search yields no results. Can anybody confirm or deny? Thanks.

---

[image]

Comment: No, that’s not in the Bible.

Comment: If a sentence is in the bible, just Googling it will bring up the reference.

Comment: I don't think a joke from a TV show known for it's religious cynicism counts as "on topic" for this site. This site strives to document extant Christian beliefs and history. The Simpsons strives to make fun of it, among other things.

Comment: This is also perhaps a verse identification question, which have been off-topic for about 4 years. Then it's also perhaps primarily opinion based, if you mean to ask "what does this mean". There's quite a few reasons this should be closed.

Comment: it wasn't a joke

Answer (score 4):

**"There's more sanctity in a dog's loyalty than there is in all your human laws."**

The above quote is not of biblical origin and can not be found in Scripture.

References to dogs in the bible are extremely rare. Most are in an unfavourable light, but not all.

In the [Book of Tobit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Tobit), ***”man’s best friend”*** accompanies Tobiah on his journey to Media.

> Tobit's dog appears only twice (in 6:2 and 11:4) and plays no role in the story (actually he accompanies Tobias, Tobit's son). Like many dogs, he just shows up whenever something seems to be going on. This little detail has greatly exercised the commentators, and even now no one seems to know how the dog got into the story. - [Tobit's Dog](http://ralphriver.blogspot.com/2005/04/tobits-dog.html)

Even family pets eating scraps is a ancient custom since immemorial times. Even Jesus talked about it:

> 21 Leaving that place, Jesus withdrew to the region of Tyre and Sidon. 22 A Canaanite woman from that vicinity came to him, crying out, “Lord, Son of David, have mercy on me! My daughter is demon-possessed and suffering terribly.”
>
> 23 Jesus did not answer a word. So his disciples came to him and urged him, “Send her away, for she keeps crying out after us.”
>
> 24 He answered, “I was sent only to the lost sheep of Israel.”
>
> 25 The woman came and knelt before him. “Lord, help me!” she said.
>
> 26 He replied, “It is not right to take the children’s bread and toss it to the dogs.”
>
> 27 “Yes it is, Lord,” she said. “Even the dogs eat the crumbs that fall from their master’s table.”
>
> 28 Then Jesus said to her, “Woman, you have great faith! Your request is granted.” And her daughter was healed at that moment. - [Matthew 15:21-28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+15%3A21-28%2CMark+7%3A24-30&version=NIV)

The most macabre dog story can be found in [2 Kings 9: 30-37](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2+Kings+9&version=KJV):

> 30 And when Jehu was come to Jezreel, Jezebel heard of it; and she painted her face, and tired her head, and looked out at a window.
>
> 31 And as Jehu entered in at the gate, she said, Had Zimri peace, who slew his master?
>
> 32 And he lifted up his face to the window, and said, Who is on my side? who? And there looked out to him two or three eunuchs.
>
> 33 And he said, Throw her down. So they threw her down: and some of her blood was sprinkled on the wall, and on the horses: and he trode her under foot.
>
> 34 And when he was come in, he did eat and drink, and said, Go, see now this cursed woman, and bury her: for she is a king's daughter.
>
> 35 And they went to bury her: but they found no more of her than the skull, and the feet, and the palms of her hands.
>
> 36 Wherefore they came again, and told him. And he said, This is the word of the Lord, which he spake by his servant Elijah the Tishbite, saying, In the portion of Jezreel shall dogs eat the flesh of Jezebel:
>
> 37 And the carcase of Jezebel shall be as dung upon the face of the field in the portion of Jezreel; so that they shall not say, This is Jezebel.

[image]

[Queen Jezebel Being Punished by Jehu, by Andrea Celesti](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jezebel#/media/File:Andrea_Celesti_-_Queen_Jezabel_Being_Punished_by_Jehu_-_WGA4622.jpg)

> 9I will make the house of Ahab like the houses of Jeroboam son of Nebat and Baasha son of Ahijah. 10And the dogs will eat Jezebel on the plot of ground at Jezreel, and there will be no one to bury her.’” Then the young prophet opened the door and ran away. 11When Jehu went out to the servants of his master, they asked, “Is everything all right? Why did this madman come to you?” “You know his kind and their babble,” he replied.… - [2 Kings 9:10](https://biblehub.com/2_kings/9-10.htm)

To be called a *dog* is to be considered of low status. I guess it is not a compliment to say the least.

> There is evidence in the Bible that physical violence toward dogs was considered acceptable (1 Samuel 17:43; Proverbs 26:17). To compare a human to a dog or to call them a dog was to imply that they were of very low status (2 Kings 8:13; Exodus 22:31; Deuteronomy 23:18; 2 Samuel 3:8; Proverbs 26:11; Ecclesiastes 9:4; 2 Samuel 9:8; 1 Samuel 24:14). In the New Testament, calling a human a dog meant that the person was considered evil (Philippians 3:2 ["Beware of dogs, beware of evil workers, beware of the concision." (KJV)]; Revelation 22:15). - [No, No, Bad Dog: Dogs in the Bible](https://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/daily/ancient-cultures/daily-life-and-practice/dogs-in-the-bible/)

Comment: I'd like to point out in the last quotation, there is no such thing as "Philemon 3:2", given the Epistle to Philemon has but a single chapter. The correct reference is **Philippians 3:2** _"Beware of dogs, beware of evil workers, beware of the concision."_ (KJV) The error is in the source he is quoting, however.

Comment: A charitable effort for what I think might not even be a genuine question.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I wasn't aware of the book of Tobin. I can't help but notice how dogs stole the spotlight here – not sanctity, loyalty, the laws of man.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is the statement not in the Bible, but there is not a single reference to dogs in the Bible where dogs are described favorably, with the possible exception of Judges 7. When Gideon separated his soldiers into two groups, those who would be sent to battle and those who would be sent home, it was the ones who lapped the water from cupped hands like a dog that were chosen.

In all other instances, dogs are viewed as violent, or contemptuous, or so foolish as to be unworthy of the gift of wisdom. Dogs return to their own vomit!

Comment: You forgot: "Even the dogs eat the crumbs that fall from their master's table". This verse gives them some credibility.

Comment: Tobias' dog was cool, YBMV

Comment: *"..there is not a single reference to dogs in the Bible where dogs are described favorably.."* That was my first thought too.

Comment: @Grasper - that comparison was meant to explain the humble state of the woman Jesus was speaking to, not elevate the dog!

Comment: You all forgot,  [2 Kings 9:10](https://biblehub.com/2_kings/9-10.htm): **“And the dogs will eat Jezebel on the plot of ground at Jezreel, and there will be no one to bury her.’” Then the young prophet opened the door and ran away.”**

Answer (score 1):

That certainly was not a quote from the Bible, despite the cartoon character raising the court's Holy Bible and motioning to it, as if quoting scripture. It's a good job you asked this question, so that the not-so-cunning tactics of 'The Simpsons' to denigrate Christianity could be exposed in this instance.

A friend told me this; a real-life episode where he knocked on a door to then have a weeping woman open it. She was sobbing uncontrollably. 
"What's wrong?" he urgently asked.
"My best friend in the world has died!" she replied, rushing on to add, "We were inseparable. Nobody can ever replace her. She was my prized possession and her death has broken my heart."
Sympathetically, my friend asked who this friend was.
"My doggy, my dear, beloved doggy!" came the answer.

Could have come straight out of 'Dogtown', uh?

I just add the event to pad out what would, otherwise, be a one-word answer - "No!"

Comment: For what it's worth, the scene cast no aspersions about the church.

Comment: That's good to know, thought some viewers might have taken it as a dig at the Bible, as if it had man-made laws that were inferior to the loyalty of a dog!

Comment: No, it was quite the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

The Revised Standard Version, and NKJV both make reference to dogs in 2Sam3:8, when Abner asks if he is a dog's head belonging to Judah. Also, speaking of loyalty, it is only in reference to his being supportive of Saul. Perhaps not a favorable report for the dog, or Abner...

Might I add here that even more rare than reference to dogs in Scripture may be the unadulterated reference to Scripture or verse in adult animated television programs...

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what the judge was referring to. And he obviously knew his bible, that is certain and for sure. He quoted in round figures, same meaning exactly but different words and it is a verse I often quote myself (no pride or ego here) is in JOHN 1:17

> "For the law was given by Moses, but grace and truth came by Jesus
>   Christ."

In life we all need some Grace at various times . Unmerited love.  Agape love.

### This is what the judge  was referring to.

I see this judge as a mighty man of God. He is a judge, so he knew the law. But he also knew  the love of God. And just for a brief moment in his life, in his court, here he was aiming to get across to the jury a wonderful principle.  Obvoiously the person in his court was as guilty as sin. However he wanted to exercise "love and grace".  But he is only the judge to see that the sentence is carried out.  It was up to the jury.  He wanted to influence them hoping that they too would see it his way.  Or more to the point the way of the New Testament.

Christian love does not always run with the natural inclinations.  Nor does it spend itself only upon those for wholesome affinity is discovered.

This is where the judge was at.

Love seeks the welfare of all. And works no ill to any.

Romans 13:8

> "Owe no man any thing, but to love one another; for he that loveth
>   another hath fulfilled the law."

Here to help - not to hinder.